# Ways to import readline from sys.stdin in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I'm doing:

```py
from sys import stdin
value = stdin.readline()
```

I'm looking for a way to do this: (code doesn't work, I tried.)

```py
from sys import stdin.readline as read
value = read()
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I stick to using `stdin.readline()`?

My only reason for needing this is readability (to me) and less code, and it is for only online competitive programming, not for production-level code, where I understand that it's better to be explicit.

Comment: You cannot import a method of an object (`stdin.readline`) separately from the object (`stdin`). Incidentally, `stdin.readline()` is _more_ readable that `read()` because it explains from which source data is read.

Comment: @DYZ Thank you for your answer. In that case, is this possible to use something like `read = stdin.readline` as an alias?

Comment: It is, but _do not_.

Comment: It's possible but doing so does not add anything to your script, if anything it reduces readability. Someone reading your script would have to find where `read` is defined

Comment: @DYZ Thank you again. Do consider writing your comments as an answer so that I can accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import a method of an object (`stdin.readline`) separately from the object (`stdin`). Incidentally, `stdin.readline()` is more readable than `read()` because it explains from which source data is read.